# Http post request decoding issue golang EOF

Tags: ajax, http, post, go

Request with postman is ok but in case of ajax call http: panic serving XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX: EOF

```
func BodyToJson(r *http.Request)  map[string]interface{}{
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body);
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(r.Body).Kind())
    fmt.Println(decoder);
    var dat map[string]interface{}
    err := decoder.Decode(&dat)
    if err!= nil{
        panic(err);
    }
    return dat
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application may be posting the data as Form.

You may have to use the following code to parse the data.

```
r.ParseForm()
defer r.Body.Close()
log.Println(r.Form)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the header Content-Type.
And maybe this example can be helpful.

```
if request.Method == "POST" {
    dat := make(map[string]interface{})
    if postData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else if err = json.Unmarshal(postData, &dat); err != nil{
        panic(err)
    } else {
        //use dat....
    }
}
```